# JS - Display a text on first else inside a loop

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using a for loop and inside it i am using `if` `else if`.

The loop basically displays messages, first it displays the messages that arrived within 30 days and then it displays the messages that are more than 30 days old.

But I need to put a divider saying `The following notifications are older than 30 days` If i put this inside the `else if` it starts to appear on top of every message inside `else if`

```
       _.forEach(this.collection.models, function(model, index){

            <%
            var createdDateTime= new Date(created_at);
            var currentDateTime= new Date();
            var difference = Math.round((createdDateTime- currentDateTime) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))

            if(difference > -30 ) { %>
            <div class="notification-box <%- read != true ? 'unread' : '' %>" data-type="<%- deeplink_type %>" data-id="<%- deeplink_id %>">
              <p class=""><%- message %></p>
              <p class="light-grey-text datetime-text" style="margin-top:0.5em;"><%- created_at %></p>
            </div>
            <% } else if(difference < -30 ) { %>

           <div class="blue banner server-banner" style="min-height: 25px; width: 100%; color: #fff; font-size: .7em; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px;">
              The following notifications are older than 30 days
            </div>

            <div class="notification-box <%- read != true ? 'unread' : '' %>" data-type="<%- deeplink_type %>" data-id="<%- deeplink_id %>">
              <p class=""><%- message %></p>
              <p class="light-grey-text datetime-text" style="margin-top:0.5em;"><%- created_at %></p>
            </div>
            <% } %>
       });
```

So my question is, how can i only display the text i want on the first iteration of `else if`.

Comment: Add a boolean check, If the item has not been added yet, than add it, next iteration the boolean will be flipped and you can ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's how I would do it. You need a boolean value to know that you went in that `else if` condition at least one time. Then using this boolean value inside your `else if` will ignore since you will set it to `true` the first time you go in it.

```
var isAlreadyDisplayed = false; 
_.forEach(this.collection.models, function(model, index){

        <%
        var createdDateTime= new Date(created_at);
        var currentDateTime= new Date();
        var difference = Math.round((createdDateTime- currentDateTime) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))

        if(difference > -30 ) { %>
        <div class="notification-box <%- read != true ? 'unread' : '' %>" data-type="<%- deeplink_type %>" data-id="<%- deeplink_id %>">
          <p class=""><%- message %></p>
          <p class="light-grey-text datetime-text" style="margin-top:0.5em;"><%- created_at %></p>
        </div>
        <% } else if(difference < -30 && !isAlreadyDisplayed) { 
        isAlreadyDisplayed = true;         
        %>
       <div class="blue banner server-banner" style="min-height: 25px; width: 100%; color: #fff; font-size: .7em; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px;">
          The following notifications are older than 30 days
        </div>

        <div class="notification-box <%- read != true ? 'unread' : '' %>" data-type="<%- deeplink_type %>" data-id="<%- deeplink_id %>">
          <p class=""><%- message %></p>
          <p class="light-grey-text datetime-text" style="margin-top:0.5em;"><%- created_at %></p>
        </div>
        <% } %>
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

So add a boolean check. Define before the forEach

```
var isFirst = true;
```

and inside the else

```
if(isFirst) {
    isFirst = false;
    //output html
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a true/false switch to meet your condition. Based on that condition you could populate your messages, provided the difference is in a sorted order.